# Highlighting specific row(s) in Streamlit dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, streamlit

I hope all is well with whoever reads this.

This is my first question on StackOverflow. I've been playing around with coding for years, but just really started getting into it a few months ago; but I'm still learning and have no shame in admitting it. I kind of feel like a %^^&*$ for having issues figuring this out lol.

I'm working on a little project, and needed to Highlight/color in specific rows of a CSV file I am displaying in Streamlit. I've been browsing around online, am seeing quite a few similar examples, but nothing quite matching up. I know I'm going to have to use the Pandas style function. But how to implement that is where I run into the issue.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjXdQ.png)

That is what I am currently working with code wise. Just a basic reading the CSV with Pandas.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mMDB.png)

I am trying to just highlight/fill in with color the entire row by the index number, like row 0 , ,4 , & 12 .

I was hoping someone has a good reference of what to do? As I said, I'm seeing a bunch of close things browsing around online, but nothing quite the same; and I'm having issues understanding exactly how I would implement that.

Thank for any and all help, it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Example dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3], "col2": [4, 5, 6]})
st.dataframe(df)
```

Function to highlight rows that have the number `2` in the first column.

```
def color_coding(row):
    return ['background-color:red'] * len(
        row) if row.col1 == 2 else ['background-color:green'] * len(row)
```

To achieve what you want with highlighting specific rows (not sure if you mean every 4th), maybe the easiest solution would be to add another column to your dataframe that specifies what rows should be highlighted. Then your `if` statement in the function below would become very simple.

Styling the df in streamlit

```
st.dataframe(df.style.apply(color_coding, axis=1))
```